# Recursion issue in Haskell - A syntactical issue?

Tags: haskell, recursion, syntax-error

I am having problems defining recursion in a function I have wrote. I am not sure what is wrong here, it could merly be a syntax blunder.

Basically I want to define like I have done for the Not Expression that the And expression calls the method substitute again. But I am havig issues defining substititue twice for the two expressions And can take.

```
substitute :: Expr -> [(Variable,Expr)] -> Expr
-- ...
substitute (Not e) x = substitute e x
substitute (And e1 e2) x = substitute e1 x substitute e2 x ---- ?????
```

If I get And wright then the entire function will work. :) Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Your `Not` case removes the negation, is that what you want? If so, what do you expect `substitute` to do in the `And` case?

Comment: Just for And to call the function substitution with variable e1 and e2. e1 and e2 can be any expression so the function will deal with what happens after that. Just need to be able to call substitution on these two generic types in And.

Comment: More than a syntax blunder, you exhibit symptoms of a conceptual error. You seem to be saying "what to do" (how do you substitute in (Not e)? you substitute in e) when the method of Haskell programming is to say *what it is*. What *is* the image of (Not e) under substitution x? Surely it's (Not something)! See that = sign? It's making a definition just by saying "this *is* that". A large part of functional programming culture shock comes from switching from a traditional "doing" model of programming to this "being" model. It may not be what you're used to, but it's quite sensible, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
substitute (Not e) x = Not (substitute e x)
substitute (And e1 e2) x = And (substitute e1 x) (substitute e2 x)
```

But I'm not really sure if this is what you want. You need some other cases where `substitute` does some real work.

Comment: Still, if he leaves it at that, I can foresee the next question: "Recursion issue in Haskell - why do I get runtime  errors?"

Answer (score 2):

When you say `substitute e1 x substitute e2 x`, you're passing 5 arguments to the `substitute` on the left:

`e1`, `x`, `substitute`, `e2`, `x`.

`substitute` only takes three arguments. You probably want to do something like `(substitute e1 x) && (substitute e2 x)`, but I'm not sure what it is that you want the expression to resolve to.